# Integrating use of surface distance when calculating cumulative cost-surface based on walking pace?

Tags: raster, r, dem, cost-surface, tobler

**Disclaimer**

This question is somewhat related to a number of earlier questions of mine:

- [Accumulated cost surface (Tobler's hiking function) ignoring slope using R gdistance?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278367/accumulated-cost-surface-toblers-hiking-function-ignoring-slope-using-r-gdist);
- [Calculating accumulated walking pace from starting location outwards using R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280105/calculating-accumulated-walking-pace-from-starting-location-outwards-using-r);
- [Working out travel time from gdistance's conductance values in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280197/working-out-travel-time-from-gdistances-conductance-values-in-r),

each representing a step in my struggle to implement in R the calculation of isochrones around a given location, using the Tobler's hiking function. In what follows, I am going to ask something new, albeit it will entail making reference to what I have achieved in an attempt to address the problem I described in my earlier threads. Long story short: I hope this new question will not be flagged as possible duplicate.

**Background**

As said above, I was trying to calculate isochrones around a start location using the Tobler's hiking function (solved for time). I believe I eventually got something right, building on the `gdistance` package's documentation (https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2014-11-17/web/packages/gdistance/vignettes/gdistance.pdf).

Below is a reproducible example, before I ask my new question:

First, load the gdistance library and a sample dataset (DTM):

```
library(gdistance)    
dtm <- raster(system.file("external/maungawhau.grd", package="gdistance"))
```

Secondly, calculate the terrain slope:

```
altDiff <- function(x){x[2] - x[1]}
hd <- transition(dtm, altDiff, 8, symm=FALSE)
slope <- geoCorrection(hd)
```

Thirdly, apply the Tobler's function to only those slope cells that are adjacents:

```
adj <- adjacent(dtm, cells=1:ncell(dtm), pairs=TRUE, directions=8)
speed <- slope
speed[adj] <- (6 * exp(3.5 * abs(slope[adj] + 0.05)))^-1 #s/m
```

In the above step, I used the reciprocal of the speed in m/s. *Rationale*: if we use speed, the final accumulated values will be 1/travel time (according to gdistance pdf guide; link above); therefore, I use the reciprocal of speed to eventually get travel time/1; travel time will be in seconds, and will require to be divided by 3600 to get hours.

Fourthly, geocorrection of the speed values (well, we should call "pace" not "speed"):

```
Conductance <- geoCorrection(speed)
```

Finally, accumulating the speed (i.e., pace) from a location:

```
A <- c(2667670, 6479000)
accum_sec <- accCost(Conductance, A)
accum_hour <- accum_sec/3600
```

What we get using `rasterVis` is the image further below:

```
levels <- seq(min(values(accum_hour)), max(values(accum_hour)), 0.15)
rasterVis::levelplot(accum_hour, par.settings = RdBuTheme, margin=FALSE, contour=TRUE, at = levels, lty=3, labels = list(cex = 0.7), label.style = 'align')
```

[image]

**Given the background, here is the question**

While the result looks quite good, in order to best mimic part of what is done by arcGIS's Path Distance tool (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-the-path-distance-tools-work.htm), I am wondering if is it possible to take into account surface distance in the calculation of the accumulated cost-surface, not the planar distance?

In other words, when passing from cell A to B, the cost should be (as customary) the average of A and B (since the traveller experiences half of the cost of the origin cell and half of the cost of the destination cell), *but* multiplied by the surface (not planar) distance (which could be quite easily derived using the Pytagorean theorem knowing the elevation difference between A and B, and their distance).

While in theory the above sounds easy, I cannot figure out how to actually integrate that to the workflow I have described earlier in this thread.

Comment: In fact, if I understand well your question, that's what you take into account using this part: `adj <- adjacent(dtm, cells=1:ncell(dtm), pairs=TRUE, directions=8)
speed <- slope
speed[adj] <- (6 * exp(3.5 * abs(slope[adj] + 0.05)))^-1 #s/m` . There you correct the speed with the slope of adjacent cell.s